# XUL to add toolbar for thunderbird

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

im new to XUL and thunderbird development. i need to add a toolbar to the messengercompose.xul file. how should i write the XUL file for that?

Comment: i've completed the XUL part as of now. i now have a new issue, that is, i need to, on a button click call on an event in one of my jars. the problem here is that the addonmanager is undefined in the messengercompose window, unlike in the messenger window